# Print a number that number of times

Tags: code-golf, number

## Example

Input -> 5
Output -> 55555

Input -> 12
Output -> 121212121212121212121212

## Criteria

Least number of bytes wins!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unfortunately, this challenge has already been asked before. In the future, you can try posting your challenge in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31716) to get feedback on it before posting it to the main site.

Comment: ...except that this question is better since it does not ban built-in functions ;p

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8PT//w2NAA "05AB1E – Try It Online") - 1 byte